# Cannot get base url right

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get the **base url** of my website.

But not matter what I try,I only get `https://127.0.0.1/magento`

I want to get https://127.0.0.1

I tried

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB)
```

and all the associated techniques with object manage but always give the same result.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
//use Vendor\Module\Model\FidoServiceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Register extends Template
{
    private $fidoCallerFactory;
    private $session;
    // public function __construct(Context $context, FidoServiceFactory $fidoServiceFactory, Session $session) {
    //     parent::__construct($context, []);
    //     $this->fidoServiceFactory = $fidoServiceFactory;
    //     $this->session = $session;
    // }
    //
    // #Returns the base URL of currently visited store.
    public function getBaseUrl() {
    //  console.log($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl());
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK);
      //return "http://127.0.0.1";

    }
```

Comment: what will be the URL

Comment: https://127.0.0.1/magento4/customer/account/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this so that beginners in Magento will not get confused again. If you use getbaseurl in localhost, you will also get the name of the directory that you are in.

This won't be affecting while you migrate to a live server.

You can easily use rtrim to get rid of the name of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
```

I think you are using wrong variable for calling object manager. you have created object manager in variable `$storeManager` and used `$this->_storeManager`

Comment: It gave the same answer :(

Comment: Have you tried frontend deployment? I dont know if it is necessary in your case, but give it a try, and clear cache.
I have used this code in my block and it's working

Answer (score 0):

try use this code:

```
$this->getBaseUrl()
```

or

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Comment: Did not work :(